# How to transform String to decimal with two fractional digits in IIB

Tags: xpath

I'm working on a mapping in IBM Integration Bus and I want to transform a field string from DFDL format to decimal with two fractional digits. But I want the two fractional digits to appear even if they are zero.

For example:

My String on the DFDL: 0058700
Expected result: 587.00

I tried the following xpath code

```
($valor cast as  xs:decimal?) div 100
```

but it didn't work, it didn't show the two decimal digits
 (ie: 587)

I Also tried defining a simple type with a pattern:

```
<simpleType name="D10"> 
      <restriction base="decimal">
        <totalDigits value="10"/>
        <fractionDigits value="2"/>
        <pattern value="[0-9]{1,12}[.][0-9]{2}"/>
      </restriction>
    </simpleType>
```

Comment: Do you have access to XPath 3.0 and http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-format-number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your string in the DFDL-described format is '0058700' but its logical value is actually '587.00' then you need to use the dfdl:textNumberPattern property to tell DFDL that is the case. A pattern of "####0V00" should do the trick. The 'V' indicates the position of the (virtual) decimal point.